# How can I show messagebox when user register successfully and redirect him to Login page?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

My signUp button event is

```
protected void signup_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string con = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connection"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(con);
        conn.Open();
        if (selectques.SelectedItem.Text == "Write your own question?")
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into registration values('" + username.Text + "','" + passwrd.Text + "','" + emailadd.Text + "','" + alterquestion.Text + "','" + securityanswer.Text + "')", conn);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");
            try {
                ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "Message", "alert('Successful Registered');window.location='login.aspx';", true); 
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
            }
        }
        else
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into registration values('" + username.Text + "','" + passwrd.Text + "','" + emailadd.Text + "','" + selectques.Text + "','" + securityanswer.Text + "')", conn);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Response.Redirect("login.aspx");
            try
            {
                ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "Message", "alert('Successful Registered');window.location='login.aspx';", true);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }
        }
    }
```

After registering successfully how can I show a message of `Successful Registered` on login page or on the same page. I want to show the message through Popup window or messagebox.

Comment: Remove both "Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");" and check...

Comment: An answer below brought up a very good point, your SQL code here is extremely dangerous.  Aside from obvious SQL injection issues, you shouldn't be executing SQL directly within an ASP.NET page.  For maintainability you should separate out your data access code from your web layer code.

Comment: @Nalaka526 thank you very its solved my problem. I got it after told by you that I'm redirecting it on another page before executing the code I need. Thank you Post it as answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove both `Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");` and check.

Answer (score 3):

A little UI design tip - people HATE popups. Your proposed idea would, of course, need JavaScript - some people have that disabled. *Not* an accessible solution. The simplest way would be to pass a parameter via GET (you could also use sessions) to `login.aspx` telling it to echo an additional message at or near the top of the page saying the registration was successful, perhaps with CSS styling to make it look like a window.

But please, no `alert`s and no popups. It's very poor design.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure you should read up on SQL Injection too because what you're doing here is very dangerous.

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(
  "insert into registration values('" + 
  username.Text + "','" + passwrd.Text + "','" + 
  emailadd.Text + "','" + alterquestion.Text + "','" +
  securityanswer.Text + "')", conn);
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're posting a form when clicking the signup button, which means you'll need to render a bit of JavaScript to show the popup then to redirect, rather than doing the redirect server side.

Your other option would be to call your register action through AJAX, and if the signup is successful, again show the alert client side and also redirect client side.

Comment: I don't know about AJAX can you help me for that?

Comment: This is a pretty extensive thing to go over, I can point you in the direction of some information though:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29

I recommend using JQuery for simple applications: http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/.

Answer (score 0):

Move `Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");`